# SpringMVC can't write entity to json

Tags: java, json, getter

I hava got an error - MyOrder can't write to json because of temperatureRangeStr's null point exception when I use springmvc.

The error happens when I write the code following:

```java
@Data
public class MyOrder {
    
    private Integer needThermometer;
    
    private Integer temperatureRangeStart;
    
    private Integer temperatureRangeEnd;

    private String temperatureUnit;

    public String getTemperatureRangeStr(){
        // here is the error happens
        if(needThermometer != null && needThermometer == 1){
            return temperatureRangeStart + "~" + temperatureRangeEnd + temperatureUnit;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

But when I have changed the code like this, the error disappears.

```java
@Data
public class MyOrder {

    private Integer needThermometer;

    private Integer temperatureRangeStart;

    private Integer temperatureRangeEnd;

    private String temperatureUnit;

    public String getTemperatureRangeStr(){
        // here is the error happens
        if(needThermometer != null){
            return (needThermometer == 1) ? temperatureRangeStart + "~" + temperatureRangeEnd + temperatureUnit : "";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can you please try like this?

```
private int needThermometer;

private int temperatureRangeStart;

private int  temperatureRangeEnd;

private String temperatureUnit;

public String getTemperatureRangeStr(){

        return (needThermometer == 1) ? temperatureRangeStart + "~" + temperatureRangeEnd + temperatureUnit : "";
    
    return "";
}
```